# Creating a free mailer the HTML form does not post to the PHP code

Tags: php, html, mailer

I'm trying to create a free email sender but to no avail.

I Use the PHP script alone to send the Mail message containing the HTML template, it goes just smooth and delivers fine.

However when i try to send it using my website the HTML template doesn't arrive.

The following PHP snippet does not work in conjunction with the HTML code :

```
<?Php
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= (isset($_POST['message']));
$message .= "</body></html>";
>
```

However without the HTML only PHP I manage to send.

```
$message = "<html><body>example</html></body>"
```

I think that the problem is with my HTML form.

```
<br><b>Your Message:</b><br>
<textarea type="html" name="message" rows="5" cols="50"style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
<br>
```

I'm no expert in this, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the isset() in the second line:

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= (isset($_POST['message']));
$message .= "</body></html>";
```

This will  only put (TRUE) inside the Body ;-)

change it to:

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= $_POST['message'];
$message .= "</body></html>";
```

Do all checks  like  **if(empty())**  before.

Comment: I've already did that, still it doesn't work, i realised that that i'm able to send HTML snippets the problem is sending the CSS my HTML code doesn't send the user input if it is CSS it only proccess plain text and html code, the problem isn't with my PHP, thank u for your contribution my friend.

Comment: CSS is no content, it's just the formatting  instructions of the content.

Comment: CSS is no content, it's just the formatting  instructions of the content.    The User posts CSS code in the form?   Why in the world would you send CSS without any info   per email?   But even this can be done you could send any code per email if it is properly escaped. BTW:  if you add the required tag to the text area the form will not be submitted  without data

Comment: Does it work now? If not post an example of a posted message.